# Why "Configuration" section of running job is empty?

Tags: apache-flink

Can anybody explain me why "Configuration" section of running job in Apache Flink Dashboard is empty?

[image: Empty Configuration section in Apache Flink Dashboard]

How to use this job configuration in my flow? Seems like this is not described in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration tab of a running job shows the values of the `ExecutionConfig`. Depending on the version of Flink you might will experience a different behaviour.

#### Flink <= 1.0

The `ExecutionConfig` is only accessible for finished jobs. For running jobs, it is not possible to access it. Once the job has finished or has been stopped/cancelled, you should be able to see the `ExecutionConfig`.

#### Flink > 1.0

The `ExecutionConfig` can also be accessed for running jobs.